# Style content within table cell without adding an extra tag?

Tags: html, css, html-table, cell

I have content within a table:

```
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
```

The table cells themselves have styling (like background-color and borders), but I want to have a circle around the numbers (not using images), using border-radius (with height, width etc.)... but I don't want to add an extra tag.

```
:before {content:<span>;}
```

Would be fine (and its :after selector), because I'm wrapping the element at a rendered level, but the content attribute wont render HTML tags.

Is there any way to do this, or do I have to wrap the content of each cell in another tag? Browser compatibility is Mobile Safari (webkit) as this is for a Cordova project, so use all the new methods you can think of.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it like this?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3tpeM/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

td {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

td:after {
    content: '•';
    color: #f00;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 90px;
    left: -20px;
    top: 23px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: I mean it is a great solution.

Comment: I love good solutions and good solutions should be appreciated.

Comment: This is a great solution for a full circle background, however I'm chasing a circle (as in just a border). Has to be responsive, so that's the reason I didn't go the font method (want it to be fluid). Let me know if there's any other methods, but I think I need to use another tag.